# How to manage many JMenus in CardLayoutt?

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 different views for which I want to have different `JMenu` (for `loginPanel` to not exist at all). All views I add to cards extend `JPanel` and I add them to cards. It's impossible to set `JmenuBar` to specific `JPanel` but only `JFrame` whereas I want specific `JMenuBar` for every card.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    public static JPanel cards;
    public Controller controller;

    public MainFrame() {

        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        controller = new Controller();

        setJMenuBar(controller.customMenuBar);  

        cards.add(controller.loginPanel, "login");
        cards.add(controller.prisonerAdd, "add");   
        cards.add(controller.prisonerPanel, "prisoner");
        cards.add(controller.searchView, "search");

        add(cards);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here is Controller where I initialize JPanels and add actionListeners to JComponents:

```
public class Controller {

    public UserDatabase db = new UserDatabase();
    public LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel(); // extends JPanel
    public CustomMenuBar customMenuBar = new CustomMenuBar(); // extends JMenuBar
    public PrisonerAdd prisonerAdd = new PrisonerAdd(); // extends JPanel
    public PrisonerController prisonerController = new PrisonerController();
    public SearchView searchView = new SearchView(); //extends JPanel
    public PrisonerPanel prisonerPanel = new PrisonerPanel(); // extends JPanel

    public Controller() {

        loginPanel.addLoginListener(new LoginListener());
        customMenuBar.addLogoutListener(new LogoutListener());
        customMenuBar.addChangeViewListener(new ChangeViewListener());
        prisonerAdd.addPrisonerListener(new AddPrisonerListener());
        searchView.searchPanel.addSearchPrisonerListener(new SearchPrisonerListener());

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question: "The problem is that we setJMenu to JFrame, not JPanel". You have a line where you call setJMenuBar to controller.customMenuBar. It is unclear what that object is in your controller class, please add that code.

Comment: You have a controller?  Use the controller to determine which panel should be made visible and as you do so, switch out the menus for that view

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a `ComponentListener` to each of your panels.
2. Handle the `componentShown(...)` event.
3. Whenever a panel is shown you update the JMenuBar for the related panel.